# I have issue with registration and login

Tags: javascript

I have issue with registration and login. Actually when the password is less than 8 char it's showing alert password should be >8, but still it's adding inside the object, in the same way it's not showing any error if two user names are same.Again, when i click on login with correct credentials it's showing incorrect username & password and it's showing logged in How can i solve this? Any leads, Totally new to programming.

```js
var objPeople = [
 {
  username: 'hello',
  password: '12345678'
 },
 {
  username: 'cat',
  password: 'password123'
 },
 {
  username: 'dreamer',
  password: 'password13'
 }
]

function login() {
 
 var username = document.getElementById('username').value

 var password = document.getElementById('password').value

 
 for(var i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {
 
  if(username == objPeople[i].username && password == objPeople[i].password) {
   console.log(username + ' is logged in!!!')
  
   break
  } else {
   
   console.log('incorrect username or password')
  }
 }
}


function registerUser() {
 var registerUsername = document.getElementById('newUsername').value
 
 var registerPassword = document.getElementById('newPassword').value
 
 var newUser = {
  username: registerUsername,
  password: registerPassword
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {
  
  if(registerUser == objPeople[i].username) {
   alert('That username is alreat in user, please choose another')
   
   break
  
  } else if (registerPassword.length < 8) {
   
   alert('That is to short, include 8 or more characters')
  
   break
  }
 }
 
 objPeople.push(newUser)
 
 console.log(objPeople)
}
```

```html
<form>
   <h2>Login</h2>
   <input type="text" id="username">
   <input type="password" id="password">
   <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
  </form>
  <!-- register user form -->
  <form>
   <h2>Register</h2>
   <input type="text" id="newUsername">
   <input type="password" id="newPassword">
   <button type="button" onclick="registerUser()">Register</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I hope that you are aware of the incredibly terrible security that this has? Anyone can just peek at the source code and find valid usernames and their respective password.

Comment: It's just for practicing purpose, I'm new to js. I read that username and password should be converted to base64 and they should be sent in headers. This is just for my learning purpose. Between thanks :) @BramVanroy

Comment: hello @BramVanroy please let me know some sources where I can check about login auth. I have tried searching online but didn't find any good source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

break only stop the loop, stop the function with return

```js
var objPeople = [{
    username: 'hello',
    password: '12345678'
  },
  {
    username: 'cat',
    password: 'password123'
  },
  {
    username: 'dreamer',
    password: 'password13'
  }
]

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value

  for (var i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {
    if (username == objPeople[i].username && password == objPeople[i].password) {
      console.log(username + ' is logged in!!!')
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log('incorrect username or password')
}

function registerUser() {
  var registerUsername = document.getElementById('newUsername').value
  var registerPassword = document.getElementById('newPassword').value
  var newUser = {
    username: registerUsername,
    password: registerPassword
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < objPeople.length; i++) {

    if (registerUsername == objPeople[i].username) {
      alert('That username is alreat in user, please choose another')
      return; // return instead of break here
    } else if (registerPassword.length < 8) {
      alert('That is to short, include 8 or more characters')
      return; // return instead of break here
    }
  }

  objPeople.push(newUser)

  console.log(objPeople)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <input type="text" id="username">
  <input type="password" id="password">
  <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</form>
<!-- register user form -->
<form>
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <input type="text" id="newUsername">
  <input type="password" id="newPassword">
  <button type="button" onclick="registerUser()">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah i tried return, but still it's creating duplicate username. Actually it shouldn't take the username if it already exists

Comment: another problem i'm facing is, when i click on correct user name and password(after creating new username& password), it's showing incorrect username and password for 3 times and it's displaying as logged in

Comment: for the duplicate username is a different issue, you're checking `registerUser == objPeople[i].username`, but it should be `registerUsername == objPeople[i].username`

Comment: the other problem is while you're looping, for every username/password not matched you're consoling that message, when you only need to console it at end of function. Note the function stops when user is logged in, and only exit the for loop if no match

Comment: both problem should be fixed now, let me know if you found any more issues

Comment: @ravanone the issue there is that you're doing the `if` check on every element in your `objPeople` array, until you find a match - so if the first one isn't a match, it will still log "incorrect username or password", even if there is a match later on). If this is a problem, the easiest way to handle it is to have a boolean variable, eg. `loginSuccess`, set it to false before the loop, then set it to `true` if a match is found while looping. Remove all the `console.log` statements from the body of the loop, and check on the value of `loginSuccess` after the loop is complete.